# how to make a PHP script run again on an online server if the response was 502 after it ran first time?

Tags: php

I would like first to thank everyone who is trying to help or even who read my question.
So what i am trying to do is make a script run on an online server as a cron job each 1 hour. So this will run it one time. But i need to make sure the script is successfully run. Sometimes the script gives this error after it ran **502 Bad Gateway** . So need a method please to let the script run again and again until it is successful. So how can i do that in PHP ?

[here is an image of the cron parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9BZX.png) and in the last line i put the script link

my script so far is :

```
<?php 

include '../includes/init.php';


$timeout_seconds = 3153600; // 1 year... 

// Make sure the PHP script doesn't time out
//set_time_limit(0);
//ignore_user_abort(1);

// Make sure the PHP socket doesn't time out
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', $timeout_seconds);
ini_set('mysqlnd.net_read_timeout', $timeout_seconds);


// This count to keep count of the news found
$news_count = 0;
$image_count = 0;

$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM news_feeds_list WHERE cron_file = '1' ORDER BY cron_timestamp ASC";
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlCommand);

if(!$query) {
    echo "Query Error: ".mysqli_error($query)."<br/>";
} else {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $feed_id = $row["feed_id"];
        $feed_title = html_entity_decode($row["feed_title"]);
        $feed_name = $row["feed_name"];
        $feed_url = $row["feed_url"];
        $feed_region = $row["feed_region"];
        $feed_length = $row["feed_length"];
        $feed_notes = $row["feed_notes"];
        $feed_subject = $row["feed_subject"];
        $feed_source_url = $row["feed_source_url"];
    
        libxml_get_errors();
    
        // Here we insert the news into database
        $url = "$feed_url";
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

        if($xml === false){
            echo "Operation failed<br/><br/>";
            continue;
        } else {
            // Success
            echo "Success<br/><br/>";

            for($i = 0; $i < $feed_length; $i++) {
                $news_count++;

            $title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
            $description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
            $description_html = htmlentities($description);
            $link = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
            $pubDate = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate;
            $author = $xml->channel->item[$i]->author;
            $title1 = str_replace("'", "\'", $title);
            $description1 = strip_tags($description, '<p><b>');
            $description1 = str_replace("'", "\'", $description1);
            $author1 = str_replace("'", "\'", $author);
            $feed_source_image = $xml->channel->item[$i]->image['url'];
            $feed_image = $xml->channel->item[$i]->enclosure['url'];
            // $feed_image will be empty so I can fetch the image from the html of the source
            $news_timestamp = time();

            // Here we convert pubDate which is a string to a timestamp
            $time = strtotime($pubDate);
            
            $time = strtotime($pubDate);
            $imageLink = "";
            $imgexists = false;

            if($feed_image == ""){
                //echo "<b>feed_image is empty!</b><br><br/>";
                 
                // UNTILL HERE THE SCRIPT RUNS WELL BUT AFTER I ADD THE CURL THE 502 COMES IN

                //we do this only if the feed_image is empty
                // HERE WE START LOOKING FOR AN IMAGE FROM THE WEBSITE ITSELF IF THE XML DOESNT CONTAIN ANY IMAGES
                //Get the page's HTML source using file_get_contents.
                // We use the following to not get an SSL error

                $curl = curl_init();
                // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $location_url);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

                $result = curl_exec($curl);
                
                curl_close($curl);




                // end of if(feed_image = "")
            } else {
                echo "<i>feed_image is not empty!</i><br><br/>";
            } // end of else (feed_image = "")

        }

    } // end of else $xml === false


} // end of first while
mysqli_free_result($query);

$sqlCommand2 = "DELETE FROM news_feeds WHERE news_title = ''";
$query_cleaning = mysqli_query($connection, $sqlCommand2);

if (!$query_cleaning) {
    echo("Error Cleaning description: " . mysqli_error($query_cleaning)."<br/><br/>");
}

echo "news count: ".$news_count."<br/>";
echo "image count: ".$image_count."<br/>";

} // end of Query Error check

 ?>
```

thank you so much

Comment: You should run this script via PHP-CLI instead of calling it by using `wget`.

Comment: what do you mean ? I am not using any wget in the script, i just search what is it, it seems it is a command line

Comment: Can you show your cronjob command?

Comment: so wget is the cron job which i usually do from my online server provider, so i dont use literally wget but i use the UI. can you please explain what do you mean by PHP CLI and how can i use it to make a cron job and run the script every 1 hour ? @vietnguyen09

Comment: Just update your answer with cronjob command.

Comment: @vietnguyen09 i don't know the command literally because i go to user interface and select 1 for hours then i click on Add cron

Comment: When you set up your cronjob command from your UI, what exactly params you put in? Can you update your answer with a few screenshots?

Comment: ok i added screenshot with last line where i place my script link starting with the folder and then the php script name .php

Comment: Are you trying to make a cURL call to your OWN server? Stop that if so, and retrieve the image from the filesystem and not Apache -  HTTP errors will not even come into it if you you just use something like `file_get_contents()`

Comment: @delboy1978uk ah no i am not at all trying to make curl call to my server ! the link will be for example this http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_sport.rss 
when i used file_get_contents() alone i got some errors sometimes but now you opened my eyes to try and do it first and if it fails then i use curl :D